# Why do multiple let statements inside a while body give a compile error?

Tags: ocaml

I'm learning OCaml and I'm struggling with this snippet:

```
let found = ref false

let () =
  while not (Queue.is_empty q) && not !found do 
    let next = Queue.pop q
    let () = found := (next.subtotal == total)
  done
```

The second let inside the while body doesn't compile, the error says 'suggested in'. Indeed, when I add a 'in' after the first let, and I remove the 'let' from the second line, it compiles.

But I don't understand why this is needed?
Doesn't Ocaml normally interpret a new 'let' as if there were an 'in' after the last line?
E.g. when I move those two lets outside of the while block, they compile fine.

Comment: "*Doesn't Ocaml normally interpret a new 'let' as if there were an 'in' after the last line?*" - no. Ocaml does however permit multiple independent `let` statements on the top level of a module.

Comment: Aha so toplevel Ocaml has slightly different grammar than elsewhere. Thx, good to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OCaml makes the distinction between local definitions and module-level definitions. In a local definition like

```ml
let g x =
  let y = 2 in (...)
```

the name `y` is only defined to be `2` inside the `(...)` subexpression.
In particular, this means that the name is only a temporary name  and accessing it later will be an error

```
let g x =
  let y = 3 in
  x + y
let error = y (* the name y is unknown in this scope *)
```

Contrarily, module-level definitions like

```
module N = struct
  let x = 0
  let y = 1
end
let ok = N.x (* [x] is a valid field of the module [N] *)
```

defines new field of the current (sub)module, which will be always be here (even if they are shadowed later).

Answer (score 0):

Aside from your misunderstanding of OCaml syntax (it happens early on) appears you're trying to determine if a queue contains a value equal to  `total`. Your approach is very imperative, which isn't especially idiomatic for OCaml.

Rather favour recursion in these cases.

```
let rec has q pred =
  if Queue.is_empty q then 
    false
  else 
    pred (Queue.pop q) || has q pred
```

The recursion might also be implemented using exception handling:

```
let rec has q pred =
  try pred (Queue.pop q) || has q pred
  with
  | Stdlib.Queue.Empty -> false
```

Then we can call:

```
let found = has q (fun x -> x.subtotal = total)
```

The explicit `if/else` isn't even necessary.

```
let rec has q pred = 
  not (Queue.is_empty q) 
  && (let v = Queue.pop q in 
      pred v || has q pred)
```

Of course, both approaches modify the queue. If we instead convert the queue to a sequence we can use `Seq.exists` and the queue is unchanged.

```
# let q = [1;2;3] |> List.to_seq |> Queue.of_seq;;
val q : int Queue.t = <abstr>
# let rec has q pred =
  if Queue.is_empty q then 
    false
  else 
    pred (Queue.pop q) || has q pred;;
val has : 'a Queue.t -> ('a -> bool) -> bool = <fun>
# has q (fun x -> x = 2);;
- : bool = true
# q |> Queue.to_seq |> List.of_seq;;
- : int list = [3]
# let q = [1;2;3] |> List.to_seq |> Queue.of_seq;;
val q : int Queue.t = <abstr>
# let has q pred = 
    q 
    |> Queue.to_seq 
    |> Seq.exists pred;;
val has : 'a Queue.t -> ('a -> bool) -> bool = <fun>
# has q (fun x -> x = 2);;
- : bool = true
# q |> Queue.to_seq |> List.of_seq;;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3]
```